# Seeking programming language which meets these few requirements

Tags: programming-languages

Seeking programming language. Must have the following qualities (in order of ascending length of feature in characters):

- Compiled
- Namespaces
- Garbage collection
- Omits OOP features!
- Fixed number of types
- Available on Mac OS X
- First-class functions
- Dynamic typing preferred
- Closures (lexical scoping)
- Can interface with C libraries (ncurses, etc)
- Availability on linux a plus but not necessary

--

To give a little more context, I want to be able to use it to write command-line utilities for linux/BSD/Mac, which may or may not use existing C libraries (such as ncurses, etc).

**Update for clarification:**

*Namespaces:* I want to avoid having to name my function `string_strip` when I could create a new namespace called `string` and define in it a function named `strip`.

*Omits OOP Features:* There's definitely a difference between a language having a feature and me not using it, versus the language intentionally omitting it. If I wanted to use [Go](http://golang.org/) but without touching anything OOP-related, I couldn't use most of the standard library.

*Fixed number of types:* Why would a languages without OOP give you the option of creating a custom "type"? What does type even mean without OOP? It would probably just be used for composition of types, ie. a Person = struct { Name, Age }, whereas you could do this with a Hash or Map just fine.

*Dynamic typing preferred:* Type inference is fine, I guess......

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_(programming_language)

Comment: one simple word defines this post - HUH?

Comment: why, what is wrong with the question?

Comment: If you added reasons for each requirement I think you could avoid more downvotes, because otherwise it seems arbitrary

Comment: Haskell (which is statically typed), specifically the GHC distribution - it's compiled (or can emit LLVM code), it uses modules which are kind of like Namespaces, it's garbage collected, it is not an OO language, I don't particularly understand 'fixed number of types', as Haskell gives you types, but you can create more, it's available on all Win/Mac/Linux, it has first class functions, and closures (functional language after all), and it can interface with C libraries.

Comment: I know of only one such language: {N/A}

Comment: @Thymine I'm not sure why he needs to justify himself.  What if it's just the features he likes?  The question is obviously detailed enough (and then some) to answer.

Comment: @Mk If its the features he likes, then it is arbitrary, if you don't want a feature don't use it, the language doesn't have to /not/ support it.  Specifically for "Omits OOP features!" and "fixed number of types" the rest of them are valid enough requirements imho

Comment: The reason I chose "fixed number of types" is because languages which allow creating new types inherently seem to add a plethora of complexity to the language which I want to avoid. A good example is Go. An array or map/hash generally suffice for composition for my purposes.

Comment: Just not using a feature that a language has isn't the same as using a language that intentionally omits that feature. For example, if I want to use Go without its OOP features, I still have to use the standard library which makes heavy use of OOP, and thus I can't really avoid it completely like I want to.

Comment: Well I'd point out that some obscure language that fulfills all your requirements, with no reason why those requirements are there, you'd end up with one that is near impossible to find references on and could have a really poor compiler and garbage collector or any other problems involved with non-maintained software.  I'd say some of your requirements are the fixes designed for problems caused by OOP practices (no specifics here), so with reasons people could point out the alternative solutions different languages have to those problems or how they avoided them in the first place

Comment: @Thymine, not having a feature in a language is quite a guarantee that this feature won't be used by the libraries written in (or for) this language. Btw., Scheme fits well - and it is not "obscure".

Comment: "What does type even mean without OOP?" Surely you're joking. Because if not... (Point in case, there's a whole lot of "type theory" with a plethora of type systems and ways to define new types, most of which has never even heard of this thing you call OOP)

Comment: @delnan: But what are they used for in most practical applications? Surely just composition?

Comment: @StevenDegutis, take a look at ML, and specifically http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner typing. You'll see what types are without all that OOP BS.

Comment: @StevenDegutis: I suggest you take a look at any functional language. Any Hindley Milner-inspired type system for starters. And if you want your mind blown, see Haskell, especially certain type system extensions (as in, not in the latest language standard). These guys do things with types you'd never imagine ;)

Comment: @SK-logic, I'd say the point of a library is to not care how its implemented, if you care what features it uses then you should implement it yourself.  if its using a feature there /should/ be a good reason to do so in its design, albeit this would not always be the case

Comment: @Thymine, try using Java libraries without being exposed to the ugly OOP. It does not matter what is inside those libraries, but their interface is still too OOPish.

Comment: @SK-logic, Not using the feature would mean not using those libraries then.  Probably 80% of the libraries and helper functions available for java have no stable equivalent in some of the languages mentioned.  Reasons would help determine what types of functions he needs from the language and which he would need to write himself no matter the language.

Comment: @Thymine: again, there are no heavily OOP libraries for C, but still, there are thousands of libraries for C. Guess why? There is no support for OOP in C!

Comment: How is that "again". No i think the reason there are thousands of libraries is because it is one of the oldest most popular languages not because there is no support for OOP.  For the record I never down voted this. Just meant to suggest that reasons would help specify that "Compiled" actually implies "the JVM is basically a show-stopper for me because it can't output a single binary that someone who does not have Java installed can execute" and that "modules" would fulfill the "Namespaces" requirement and we could have had answers like @birryree's faster, and not had the question closed

Comment: @Thymine, there are thousands of perfectly non-OOP libraries because of the lack of OOP, otherwise they'll be, obviously, OOP libraries. But yes, this nice language feature also affected the numbers as well. You've got to check out the old Open Source community attitude towards C++ and OOP (e.g., read the typical Torvalds' rants).

Comment: @SK-logic, so your point is the same as "There are thousands of perfectly non-English books, because other languages are spoken" I really have no clue what you're even responding to.  All my point was is that you can write non-OOP libraries in OOP languages, and he required being able to use C libraries, so use those instead of what is generally used with the chosen language, requiring zero OOP features in the language is therefore unnecessary

Comment: @Thymine, I can't understand what is it in what I've said that you're failing to understand. It is such a trivial logic: if the language does not provide some feature, this feature won't be in the libraries available for this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by namespaces, but aren't you describing Scheme?

Comment: I forgot to add the requirement that it can interface with C libraries and be somewhat portable (omitting Windows).. can Scheme use things like ncurses and work on Mac OS X?

Comment: If so, the question then becomes "which Scheme?", I can't find a good comparison of the available choices. Is there a de facto standard Scheme compiler these days with a useful standard library for most tasks?

Comment: @StevenDegutis take a look at http://www.call-cc.org/ It claims to do what you want (I haven't tried it).  Also please note that I find it compeltely WTF that you got -4 on this question.

Comment: as long as you're considering scheme you should look at clojure.

Comment: My biggest issue with clojure is the JVM. Otherwise I think clojure might be perfect. But the JVM is basically a show-stopper for me because it can't output a single binary that someone who does not have Java installed can execute.

Comment: Not to mention, Clojure violates the requirement of "omits OOP features"

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll try to put forth some languages that fit almost every single requirement:

- [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org) (which is statically typed)

  - specifically the GHC distribution - it's compiled (or can emit LLVM code)
  - it uses modules which are kind of like Namespaces
  - it's garbage collected, it is not an OO language
  - I don't particularly understand 'fixed number of types', as Haskell gives you types, but you can create more, and Haskell supports [algebraic types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Algebraic_data_type) and pattern matching
  - it's available on all Win/Mac/Linux
  - it has first class functions and closures (functional language after all)
  - and it can interface with C libraries.

---

- [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/)

  - it has a bytecode compiler, and if you're on an Intel x86-family CPU, there is a native compiler called  [HiPE](http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/).
  - Dynamically typed
  - Not an OO language, it's near-functional
  - Has 8 primitives and 2 compound types - if you want a collection you're building a list or tuple of them
  - Is garbage collected
  - Has (immutable) closures
  - Has first class functions
  - Windows, Mac, Linux supported
  - Has packages which act as the namespace protectors
  - C bindings - [Erlang has port drivers](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) and [Erlang Native Interface](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) (based on Scheme).

It has an FFI. I've created FFI bindings for SQLite and ODBC with it, and I've found the FFI to be useful and convenient.

"Namespaces" is ambiguous to me. Racket has a module system, and it also has what it calls namespaces, which are first-class top-level environment objects.

It does not have "a fixed number of types". I don't understand that requirement at all.

Comment: I'm not opposed to some form of Scheme.. although if I go with it, the issue is really the difficulty of editing code with such heavy use of parentheses. I cannot use emacs and only use vim, so I can't really use paredit or similar tools for emacs. The only route I think I can go if I use some Lisp is to find a good vim plugin or just deal with the pain of manually balancing and rearranging parentheses all the time. But vim really sucks at it by default.

Comment: Also, being able to create custom types creates complexity in the language which I'm trying to avoid. This complexity is visible when dealing with things such as value and type equality, for instance. I'm thinking of Go in my head when I cite these examples, but it's when you get rid of OOP there seems to be no real need for custom types, when we could just compose collections of values using arrays or maps/hashes, which seems to be the only reason I can think of for wanting a custom type outside of an OOP language.

Comment: @StevenDegutis, there are no problems editing Scheme or any other Lisp in Vim.

Comment: Then maybe it isn't a problem, which is what I'm hoping for :)

Comment: @StevenDegutis, check out the Rainbow Parenthesis vim script, this one is my favourite.